# Where's the Notification Center sound (aka Tri-tone) stored on the filesystem in 10.13?

Tags: audio, high-sierra, notifications

**NOTE:** *This is not actually a duplicate of the "[Alert Tone Audio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/where-are-the-alert-tone-audio-files-located-in-os-x)" question that folks had thought previously, but it is more or less answered there.  This "Tri-tone" audio file is not in `/System/Library/Sounds`, but it is located here:*  `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AlertTones/sms-received1.caf`

Been hunting for a bit, but not finding it.  I'd like to find Tri-tone which also serves as the Notification Center sound for all general notifications that come into the system.

I'm not seeing an AIFF file that matches it in `/System` so I'm kinda shooting blanks.

[Here's a ample of the sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYTWPHHA_BA).

Comment: As of 2022, looks like that path is protected (by SIP and the system image disk). So doing changes is much more involved. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414185/disabled-mac-os-sip-but-still-cant-delete-default-apps/414186#414186