# How to change the send/receive sound on Messages in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, audio, mojave, messages

I'm trying to change the sound Messages makes when sending out an message along with receiving one.

I've done some tinkering based on info from similiar questions on this site. For example:
[Where are the alert tone audio files located in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/where-are-the-alert-tone-audio-files-located-in-os-x)

Can someone tell me where files are located for me to make changes. I know the receive sound is called `note.m4r`. But I want to change the sending out "wooooo" sound too.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

iMessage sounds are located at

```
/Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/Received Message.aiff
/Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/Sent Message.aiff
/Applications/Messages.app/Contents/Resources/Default.aiff
```

However, changing these files do not seem to affect the sound.

Comment: I've tried putting in another sound file in this location but the change doesn't actually happen. When I send/receive I still get the tradition "wooo." would you be able to try it?

Comment: @ChrisMacChange did you name the file appropriately?

Comment: yes I did. Here I've uploaded the old school AOL IM sounds to test. https://gofile.io/?c=Z86SbJ

Comment: @ChrisMacChange Try restarting. If still not, I'm not sure

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can do it with this:
In Mail->Preferences->Rules (the rules menu of Mail), there is a possibility have sounds in setting a rule.